# Webpack 5 error "Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'" when loading fonts

Tags: webpack, sass, font-face, webfonts, sass-loader

After I added [`sass-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) to [my webpack configuration](https://github.com/aabuhijleh/reproduce-webpack-issue/blob/main/webpack.config.js), I'm getting a build error when using this node module [@fontsource/roboto](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fontsource/roboto)

```
import "@fontsource/roboto"; // this is in index.tsx
```

```
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| /* roboto-cyrillic-ext-400-normal*/
> @font-face {
|   font-family: 'Roboto';
|   font-style: normal;
    at eval (index.css:1)
    at Object../node_modules/@fontsource/roboto/index.css (index.js:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:556)
    at fn (index.js:767)
    at eval (index.tsx:6)
    at Module../src/index.tsx (index.js:62)
    at __webpack_require__ (index.js:556)
    at index.js:1613
    at index.js:1617
```

Here is my [webpack configuration](https://github.com/aabuhijleh/reproduce-webpack-issue/blob/main/webpack.config.js)

```js
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: "babel-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
        type: "asset/resource",
      },
    ],
  },
```

The build succeeds if I remove `sass-loader` from the config like this (but then I can't use sass files in my project)

```js
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
      },
```

[Here is my repo](https://github.com/aabuhijleh/reproduce-webpack-issue)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which file are you doing the import? The import is supposed to be done in a Javascript file. From the error stack trace, it seems you're trying to import in a CSS file `index.css`.

Comment: I'm importing it in my typescript index.tsx file: https://github.com/aabuhijleh/reproduce-webpack-issue/blob/main/src/index.tsx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I played with your repo locally, and seems your `css` files were not covered by any loaders. I got the build running as expected with just adding:

```
        {
          test: /\.css$/i,                                                                                                                                                             
          use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],                                                                                                                          
        },
```

if you play around with the rules, you should be able to either:

- optimize loaders, so css files are not run through `sass-loader`
- improve the general test regex so it cover all cass/scss/css files.

Comment: This is the correct regex to cover both sass and css `/\.(scss|css)$/i`. I just copied that regex from the [sass-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/) documentation without thinking about it. Thanks!